# SELECT statement in SQLite change column name

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

The query below works for MS SQL. But I am trying it out in SQLite.

```
SELECT 
'Cust_ID' =
CASE
WHEN  Cust_ID IS NOT NULL OR Cust_ID='' THEN Cust_ID
ELSE '' 
END, 
'Cust_Name' =
CASE
WHEN  Cust_Name IS NOT NULL OR Cust_Name='' THEN Cust_Name
ELSE '' 
FROM Customer
```

So the result is that we have have column "Cust_ID" and "Cust_Name" for the column header in MS SQL.

But for SQLite the header becomes:

```
'Cust_ID' =
CASE
WHEN  Cust_ID IS NOT NULL OR Cust_ID='' THEN Cust_ID
ELSE ''
```

Comment: Just use `ALIAS`

Comment: SQLite makes no promises about a column's name unless you us `... AS name`.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT x = y` is a nonstandard syntax.

Just use the standard SQL syntax to create aliases (this should work in all databases):

```
SELECT CASE ... END AS Cust_ID,
       CASE ... END AS Cust_Name
FROM ...
```